# Working with large number of Labels

Tags: multithreading, actionscript-3, large-data

(Probably a noobish question but...) I am trying to write a custom component which essentially contains a rather large table (at the largest, it should be 800 x 35 fields, of which only up to 20 x 10 is visible at a time). I was wondering if anyone could give me some pointers/advices how to do that in optimal way.

**What am I using now:** component extends `UIComponent`, I have a custom scroll-bar and use a new `spark.components.Label` as a text container for each field in the table. I put the labels inside another `UIComponent`, so I can mask label edges outside the display area. I have tried:

1. Draw only data that is contained in display area. When the user moves the scroll-bar, data is re-drawn, however, since there is still a lot of `Labels`, the component becomes a bit laggy.
2. Draw the entire table and use mask/container position to show only the part of a table represented by the position of sliders. However, it takes a long time to draw and might use a lot of memory I suppose.
3. *(Current idea)* Multithreading. This is completely new for me, so I have set up a background `Worker` and want it to return an `UIComponent` with the table drawn, while the user can continue interacting with other parts of the component.
   **So here come my questions:**

   - So far I am having trouble transferring `UIComponent` using `MessageChannel`. Is such a transfer using `MessageChannel` possible in the first place or should I use alternative approach?
   - Is there an alternative approach for similar cases? Maybe I should use different  containers for the text/table itself?
   - Maybe I should use the background worker to draw BMP and use it instead of a `UIComponent`. If so, maybe someone could refer me to a nice tutorial or guide how to do this?

Thanks for the help and let me know if you need any additional info.

-Vil

Comment: The problem in hand is not really having too much data to deal with but having too much data to display, displaying is not something a worker can help you with so this will not prevent you from having trouble. The "right" way to do it is not even part of what you are considering so moving to what you consider: At least make use of the RENDER event, field in view should be drawn but as important: field not in view should be hidden!

Comment: Are you not able to use a `List` or `Grid` component? This is exactly what those components have been optimized for. For best performance you need virtualize the layout, only draw the layout which is in view, and use pooling/recycling of items to avoid the high cost of construction. These are things that are built into Flex list based components already. Using a `Worker` is a common idea but doesn't really work for optimizing display, as workers can't handle display objects. It's more for data heavy operations, like encoding and decoding byte arrays.

Comment: Not all Flex components are actually optimized correctly or even at all unfortunately. It should be reminded they were never made with mobile optimization in mind so many are still today quite CPU expensive.

Comment: @BotMaster thanks, I'll check the event. About the 'right' way to approach this, would you care to elaborate? Maybe i should create a completely new object i.e. *LineData* for each of the lines of the table? Would that help? As both of you can see, I'm rather new to AS.

Comment: Have you looked at FlexBlitMask and/or BlitMask in the Greensock lib? There is also a full Bitmap based grid but I can not remember the name of it now. I used it a long time ago and the coders demo has 1,000 of rows and columns and since you were 'just' scrolling a bitmap it flew.

Comment: The right way is basically as you scroll the renderers going out of view are send back to a pool and reused (refilled with data) while the renderers going into view are taken from the pool. At the end you (more or less) never create more renderer than you need to cover the entire display area. All the calculation are done by math only (renderer size and position) and is pretty much virtual since there's no object that really move out of view or in view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it took me a while to re-write the code but ended up doing what @BotMaster suggested (or at least my work was in that direction). So now:

- For data rows I created a separate object containing labels and it also handles horizontal scrolling internally. This way when I adjust vertical scrollbar, I move the entire container instead of moving each element individually.
- In the beginning of the program I initialize sufficient number of elements (row elements and row/column labels) and store them in separate `ArrayCollection`-s. Than, upon scrollbar update:

  - Calculate the new visible area.
  - Check if elements in current display list are in the new area. If they are not - I move them from display list to their respective `ArrayCollection`-s, containing unused elements.
  - Adjust the position of remaining elements in the display list.
  - If there is space in the new visible area, I take elements from respective `ArrayCollection`-s, adjust their text and position an put them back in display list.

The scrolling now is much smoother than before.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem (as I see it) is that Text gets re-rendered every frame.  If you had a 10,000 line TextField and masked off all but the first few lines, Flash will still render all 10,000 lines before then masking.

As others have mentioned, the solution is to handle the rendering yourself; blitting the portions you want to see onscreen.  As long as the other components remain `visible.false`, or generally just off the DisplayList, they won't get rasterized by the environment.

[Greensock's BlitMask](https://greensock.com/blitmask) does exactly that.

Comment: Don't use this if you target mobile devices, the performance hit will be too big. BitmapData drawing is probably required somewhere but caching the entire renderer might not be necessary and so this Greensock engine might cost you more than it will save you.